I want to group the "Agent Location" (Having different Agent Codes) into one single Agent Location



Agent Code
Zone
Agent Location




7795
East
Kolkata SBM


8080
South
Chennai


8069
South
Bangalore


8065
North
Delhi


8073
West
Mumbai


8092
East
Noida


8083
South
Hyderabad


8218
South
Bangalore


8064
West
Bihar


8077
East
Noida


8062
South
Hyderabad


8070
South
Bangalore


8213
South
Bangalore


Grand Total





As you can see in the above table, the "Agent Location" Bangalore has multiple "Agent Code". I would like to merge all the values mentioned under "Bangalore" into one and show it as "Bangalore" and the cumulative value of the corresponding Agent codes.

Have you tried using a pivot table?

You can use GROUPBY()--> =GROUPBY(C2:C14,A2:A14,ARRAYTOTEXT,,0)

I have a question why do you want a cumulative value of the Agent Codes? Agent Codes are like IDs I assume, should be grouped per location wise. Could you clarify more, with your expected output.

I agree that ID's are for identification, not for summing. I think instead of cumulative value you mean joined.
In that case =LET(u,SORT(UNIQUE(C2:C14)),HSTACK(u,MAP(u,LAMBDA(x,ARRAYTOTEXT(FILTER(A2:A14,C2:C14=x)))))) is the GROUPBY equivalent if you don't have access to that BETA introduced function yet.
